# Load domain values from .xml when creating PostGIS database with ili2db from .ili

Tags: postgis, postgresql, interlis

I'm trying to create a PostGIS database with ili2pg. This creates a proper database schema. There is an additional .xml file with domain-values. I think these values aren't loaded in the process. How can I load them to the database schema?

I'm using PostgreSQL 11 with PostGIS 2.5 and ili2pg 4.3.0 on Windows 10
ili-Model is "Minimales Geodatenmodell - Langsamverkehr" --> Hpm_Network_V1.ili with the additional Hpm_Catalogues_V1.xml
from https://www.astra.admin.ch/astra/de/home/fachleute/weitere-bereiche/geoinformation/geobasisdaten/langsamverkehr.html or Model Repository: https://models.geo.admin.ch/ASTRA/

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, maybe still helpful for somebody.

Catalogue items are imported with `ili2pg` too:

- Generate the database from ili model with *ili2pg*: `ili2pg --schemaimport --dbusr usr1 --dbpwd pwd --setupPgExt --dbdatabase Interlis_test --dbschema Hpm_Network --createEnumTabs --createEnumTabsWithId --beautifyEnumDispName --createFk --createFkIdx --defaultSrsCode 2056 --log schemaimport-log.txt --trace Hpm_Network_V1.ili`
- **Import Catalogue items** from the Interlis xml-transferfile with *ili2pg*: `ili2pg --import --dbusr usr1 --dbpwd pwd --dbdatabase Interlis_test --dbschema Hpm_Network Hpm_Catalogues_V1.xml`

  → The table *hpm_catalogues* gets the Catalogue items.

Further information:

- Readme for ili2pg: [ili2db-readme](https://github.com/claeis/ili2db/blob/master/docs/ili2db.rst) (valid for each ili2xx).
- [Hilfsmittel für die Geodatenmodellierung](https://www.geo.admin.ch/de/geo-information-switzerland/geobasedata-harmonization/geodata-models.html#hilfsmittel-fr-die-geodatenmodellierung).
- If you would ever have to create Catalogue items yourself, this is an app for creating them from an Excel table: [xls2xtf](https://github.com/claeis/xls2xtf).

Comment: I managed it in the meantime by myself. But thanks a lot for the answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolo! @GISDani, if you solve your question by yourself, next time you can post the answer and even mark it as accepted.